# JavaFX: Disable all Buttons from a ToggleGroup

Tags: user-interface, javafx, togglebutton

Like the title says, i want to disable all Buttons in a Togglegroup. I know it is possible to select the Buttons individually and `button.setDisable(true)`.

But is there a possibillity like `group.setDisable(true)`?

Thanks for any help or hints.

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the toggles are in the same container (`Group` or `Pane`), and there is nothing else in that container (at least, nothing that you care about being disabled, so `Label`s might be OK), then you can just disable the container (the disabled state propagates to child nodes).

Otherwise there is no direct way to do this: you can just iterate through the toggles, use the appropriate cast, and disable it:

```
toggleGroup.getToggles().forEach(toggle -> {
    Node node = (Node) toggle ;
    node.setDisable(true);
});
```